# Proving symmetry of metric (single linkage between clusters using arbitrary dissimilarity measure)

Tags: statistics, metric-spaces, proof-verification, proof-writing, clustering

I am told to assume that our dissimilarity measure $d$ satisfies the properties required of it, what seems to be the definition of a metric:

$d(x,y) \geq0 $ and $d(x,y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=y$

$d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

$d(x,z)\leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$

Given that, we define single linkage to be $$d(A,B)=\min_{x\in A, y\in B}\{d(x,y)\}$$
We are told to assume that our dissimilarity measure $d$ satisfies the properties above.

I want to prove (or contradict...) $$d(A,B)=d(B,A)$$

Since I know $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ it seems like it ought to be straightforward.

Suppose we have $x\in A , y\in B$, then $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ still holds, as far as I can see.

$\Rightarrow \min\{d(x,y)\}=\min\{d(y,x)\}$

$\Rightarrow \min_{x\in A, y\in B}\{d(x,y)\} = \min_{x\in A, y\in B}\{d(y,x)\} $

$\Rightarrow d(A,B)=d(B,A)$ as required.

Does this constitute an adequate proof? Can someone help me make it a little more rigorous? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: For example if $A=[0,1]$ and $B=(1,2)$ then what is $d(A,B)$? That is why everyone was telling you to use the infimum rather than the minimum (similar but subtly different things)

Comment: This problem was given in statistics, where the sets $A$ and $B$ consist of multivariate data points. I hadn't considered how I would approach the problem when it involves open and closed intervals. I am unsure now what your comment means for my attempt at a proof.

Comment: @user142340 I think your proof for showing $d(A,B)=d(B,A)$ is absolutely correct. The fact that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ is the key.