# For $A,B,C\subset X$where $X$ is a metric space under some $d$, check if the triangle inequality holds for $d_m(A,B)=\min_{x\in A,y\in B}\{d(x,y)\} $

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-verification

$$d_m(A,B)=\min_{x\in A,y\in B}\{d(x,y)\} $$
Is it the case that $$d_m(A,C)\leq d_m(A,B)+d_m(B,C)$$ based on the definition of $d_m$ and the fact that $d$ is already some arbitrary metric on $X$?

I am rather unsure how to start this particular problem. I already know $$d(x,z)\leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$$ from the fact that $d$ itself is a metric on $X$, which I imagine will be useful.

However, I need a hint to help me towards proving (or contradicting) the statement in the question. Any starting points will be appreciated.

Comment: @muffle If $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ then $d(A,B)=0$ and similarly for $B\cap C$. Now if $A\cap C=\emptyset$, $d(A,C)>0$, so it doesn't hold.

Comment: @SuzuHirose $A\cap B=\emptyset$ does not imply $d(A,B)>0$

Comment: @Chazz - yes it does, for a metric $d(x,y)>0$ unless $x=y$. Anyway we only need a counterexample here.

Comment: @Chazz I'd have thought it does, if our metric $d$ (referred to in my question as $d_m$ is defined as $$d_m(A,B)=\min_{x\in A,y\in B}\{d(x,y)\} $$
Can you explain why it doesn't?

Comment: @user142340 Consider for example $X=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the usual metric;  $A=\lbrace (x,y)| y>\frac{1}{x}\,,\, x>0\rbrace$ and $B=\lbrace (x,y) | y=0\rbrace$

Comment: OK, I can see now from your example that it's not automatically true for all sets $A,B$ and all metrics $d$. But in the case of this metric $d_m$, it is true to say $A\cap B = \emptyset \Rightarrow d(A,B)=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose A and B have a point in common, and B and C have a point in common, and A and C have no points in common.

**Spoiler:**

> If $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ then $d(A,B)=0$ and similarly for $B\cap C$. Now if $A\cap C=\emptyset$, $d(A,C)>0$, so it doesn't hold.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was a bit puzzled initially but the spoiler makes it fairly clear. I had actually used a similar line of reasoning in trying to show that the 'first' property of a metric doesn't hold either; 
in determining if $d(A,B)=0 \Longleftrightarrow A=B$ I said suppose $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$, then $$\min_{x\in A, y\in B}\{d(x,y)\}=0 $$ so $d(A,B)=0$ but $A\neq B$.


I think it's true that $d(A,B)\geq 0$.

Comment: I am having difficulty proving, or rigorously proving, the symmetric property in this case (I have been asked to test all the properties, it's not accepted to stop since one has been shown to fail).
I posted it separately at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030380/proving-symmetry-of-metric-single-linkage-between-clusters-using-arbitrary-diss
I'd really appreciate any help you can offer on that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create some extreme situations where the claim fails. Take $\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean metic, and consider $A$ and $C$ to be some really far away subsets, say even just a singleton each, but far away. Clearly, $d(A,C)>0$. Now for $B$ you can choose all of $\mathbb R$. What happens then?

Remark: the minimum in the definition of distance between subsets need not be attained. One thus uses the infimum.

Comment: This is a good counter-example.

Comment: I've tried thinking through your example, hopefully I'm following. So suppose $A$ is a singleton set arbitrarily small, and since $B$ covers all of $\mathbb{R}$ then the minimum distance between points in $A$ and $B$ is going to be very small. Similar for $B$ and $C$ if $C$ is an arbitrarily large singleton set. And the sum of these two will be small. And not greater (or equal to) than the distance between the singletons $A$ and $C$ as is required by the triangle inequality. Is that a decent handwavey interpretation of the logic there?

Comment: Can anyone help me with examining the other properties of this metric? I posted my efforts in a separate query so as to give me a chance to ask about both properties independently, but the other post got no responses. Everyone's help is much appreciated.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030380/proving-symmetry-of-metric-single-linkage-between-clusters-using-arbitrary-diss

Answer (score 0):

You need to use infimum instead of minimum in the definition.

Let $A\subseteq X$ and define $d(x,A)=\inf\lbrace d(x,a) |a\in A\rbrace$, you can prove that

- $d(x,A)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,A)$

Then for $A,B, C\subseteq X$, let $c\in C$, now

$$\begin{align}
d(A,B)=&\inf\lbrace d(a,b)| a\in A\;,b\in B\rbrace\\
&=\inf \lbrace d(a,B) |a\in A\rbrace\\
&\leq \inf\lbrace d(a,c)+d(c,B) |a\in A\rbrace\\
&\leq \inf \lbrace d(a,c) |a\in A\rbrace +d(c,B)\\
&=d(A,c)+d(c,B)\quad\quad \forall\; c\in C
\end{align}
$$

and that is the best you can say regarding a "triangle inequality".

Comment: This question was asked in a statistical context, hence the 'minimum' in the question (and also my ineptitude with metric spaces proofs...)
Would you mind taking a look at my attempt at proving the symmetric property of this particular metric? I included my approach in a separate post which didn't get much attention.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030380/proving-symmetry-of-metric-single-linkage-between-clusters-using-arbitrary-diss

Comment: The error in your logic is that you've insisted that the same point $c$ has to be used in both d(A,C) and d(C,B).

Comment: @SuzuHirose Yes, you are right. It does hold if instead you define the distance as $d(A,B)=\sup_{a\in A} d(a,B)$.